# How to calculate the transmission ( channel ) bandwidth in a digital communications system?

Tags: digital-communications, bandwidth

Is it the bandwidth ( BW ) of the individual pulse or should I generate a random process and calculate the BW from its **PSD**.
In my class we considered it the bandwidth of the **raised cosine** when we were studying the **ISI**. but then when we came to the **modulation techniques** we calculated the **PSD** of the random process ( and we considered that each bit is a rect not a raised cosine ).
What is the difference between the two approaches and which one is the transmission bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

If the transmitter uses pulse shaping, then it is definitely the PSD of the pulse (raised cosine or other), not a hypothetical rectangle.

Comment: Then what does the PSD of the random process indicate?

Comment: I am not asking about whether to use a rect or a raised cosine 
I am asking about whether to use the BW of the pulse - whatever its shape is - or to generate a random process and calculate its PSD

Comment: It would be indicative of information content.  Generally pulse shaping is conducted on discrete signals.  I suppose if the random process were analog, then you would have to convolve the two PSDs.

Comment: you mean to convolve the PSD of the random process ( assuming rectangles ) with the FT of the raised cosine ?

Comment: Actually just multiply the fourier transforms (PSD is FT squared).  Convolution would be the time domain.  So the FT of the rectangle is a sync and the FT of the raised cosine is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419983/fourier-transform-of-raised-cosine
Sorry for the confusion!!!